# I don't understand why RegExp.prototype.exec() is returning null when the file I do regex on is big

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

So I have been trying to figure out why the code is not working when the data variable gets content from a big file to do the regex on.
also here is link to the file that I'm doing regex on https://easyupload.io/8cbsou

```
const fs = require("fs");

function getFilecontent(fs, filename)
{
    return fs.readFileSync(filename, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
}

async function test(re, data) 
{
    let promise = new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        let array1;
        while((array1 = await re.exec(data)) !== null)
            console.log(array1[0]);

        res("cool");
    });
    promise.then(results => {console.log(results)});
}

let data = getFilecontent(fs, 'lol').toString();
test(/"Market":/g, data);
```

Comment: by the way .... `await re.exec`? in fact, why is `function test` even `async`?

Comment: Honestly idk i was just trying to make the code work hoping await/async could fix it

Comment: You say your code 'returns null' ... where is this returned null? - the only return is in `getFilecontents` ... if that is returning null, then `re.exec` has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: I have changed the code so much i forgot to say it's not console.log() matches the expression in while loop should not be == to null but it is for some reason because the string is big

Comment: Is it a JSON file? `"Market":` looks like part of a JSON object. If so, you should use `JSON.parse()` to parse it, not a regexp.

Comment: some of it is i think but not all of it it would really help me out if i can get solution to my problem with regex i just dont understand why it wont work

Comment: JSON.parse() throws error the file not complete json file

Comment: Make sure you don't reuse the same regex object for different calls of `test`. Remove `async` and `await` and `new Promise`.

Comment: NB: Windows warns me that the download file is unsafe.

Comment: You should also explain what "not working" means (Error? Execution does not finish? Wrong output? ...)

Comment: Okay so i have i have file with part of same data that when i change the code to get it the regex finds what i am looking for but when the file is large it just falls and function returns null so yes wrong output because i get no output when i should

Comment: it's a safe file when i i saved it i forgot .txt you can add it see the data in notepad

Comment: Update on my problem so one thing i confirmed is that it's whatever data is in the file that is making regex just fail and return null and that causes me to get no output the way i how i got this data was from node test.js > lol in powershell i think that someone how some chracters that cause regex to fail i hope someone can help me on this problem